# Hadoop on Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop

I just created an account on Azure and signed up for the 3 months trail. Can someone point me in the right direction for starting up with Hadoop on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a simple introduction to Hadoop on Azure by watching the [Upload data to Hadoop on Windows Azure and run the WordCount Sample](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=BvssSmYJBoc) video by Brad Sarsfield.

Besides that there's the big wiki on TechNet containig a lot of How-To articles: [Hadoop-based Services on Windows Azure How To Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6206.hadoop-based-services-on-windows-azure-how-to-guide.aspx). At they end of the wiki you'll see a list of people who work on Hadoop on Azure, I suggest you follow them on Twitter and take a look at their blogs.